# How to Use 1 file for different Action?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, redirect

I have 2 files, there are Index.aspx and AdminHome.aspx. and also have javascript file (test.js) for logic behind.

Index and adminHome is actually same but the different is only the redirect action.

If I run program from Index.aspx then i'll be redirect to CheckSeat.aspx

If I run program from AdminHome.aspx then I'll be redirect to AdminCheckSeat.aspx. I want to use same Javascript because each file has same logic. only the redirect file is the different.

this is my redirect code on .js

```
var url = "CheckSeat.aspx?noSeat=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&endtime=" + encodeURIComponent(time);                 
    window.location.replace(url);
```

so Is it possible to do ?
if ya, How do you do ?

> example URL : http://localhost90909/abcd/index.aspx

I need 'index.aspx' segment only

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the url based on current page.

```
if (document.URL = 'Index.aspx') {
    var url = "CheckSeat.aspx?noSeat=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&endtime=" + encodeURIComponent(time);
    window.location.replace(url);
}
else if (document.URL = 'AdminHome.aspx') {
    var url = "AdminCheckSeat.aspx"
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

Comment: but the URL not only show 'Index.aspx' but also http://localhost1234/abcd/Index.aspx
is it still Ok for this kind of URL ?

Comment: My answer is just representing my idea. Please add complete URL to the condition. Reference [URL of type DOMString, readonly.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437)

Comment: If just like that I've already know. the problem is how to get 'Index.aspx' segment only.